# Get all DNA encoding for a peptide in C#

Tags: c#, bioinformatics

I want to get all DNA encodings for a peptide: a peptide is a sequence of amino acids i.e. amino acid `M` and amino acid `Q` can form peptide `MQ` or `QM`.

DNA encoding means there is a DNA code (called a codon) for each amino acid (for some there are more than one code i.e. amino acid T has 4 different codes/codons).

The last function in the following code is not working, so I want to make it work. Please no query integrated language solutions (I forgot its acronym!).

```
private  string[] CODONS ={ 
    "TTT", "TTC", "TTA", "TTG", "TCT",
    "TCC", "TCA", "TCG", "TAT", "TAC", "TGT", "TGC", "TGG", "CTT",
    "CTC", "CTA", "CTG", "CCT", "CCC", "CCA", "CCG", "CAT", "CAC",
    "CAA", "CAG", "CGT", "CGC", "CGA", "CGG", "ATT", "ATC", "ATA",
    "ATG", "ACT", "ACC", "ACA", "ACG", "AAT", "AAC", "AAA", "AAG",
    "AGT", "AGC", "AGA", "AGG", "GTT", "GTC", "GTA", "GTG", "GCT",
    "GCC", "GCA", "GCG", "GAT", "GAC", "GAA", "GAG", "GGT", "GGC",
    "GGA", "GGG", };

private  string[] AMINOS_PER_CODON = { 
    "F", "F", "L", "L", "S", "S",
    "S", "S", "Y", "Y", "C", "C", "W", "L", "L", "L", "L", "P", "P",
    "P", "P", "H", "H", "Q", "Q", "R", "R", "R", "R", "I", "I", "I",
    "M", "T", "T", "T", "T", "N", "N", "K", "K", "S", "S", "R", "R",
    "V", "V", "V", "V", "A", "A", "A", "A", "D", "D", "E", "E", "G",
    "G", "G", "G", };


public  string codonToAminoAcid(String codon)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < CODONS.Length; k++)
    {
        if (CODONS[k].Equals(codon))
        {
            return AMINOS_PER_CODON[k];
        }
    }

    // never reach here with valid codon
    return "X";
}

public  string AminoAcidToCodon(String aminoAcid)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < AMINOS_PER_CODON .Length; k++)
    {
        if (AMINOS_PER_CODON [k].Equals(aminoAcid ))
        {
            return CODONS[k];
        }
    }

    // never reach here with valid codon
    return "X";
}

public string GetCodonsforPeptide(string pep)
{
    string result = ""; 
    for (int i = 0; i <pep.Length ; i++)
    {
        result = AminoAcidToCodon(pep.Substring (i,1) );
        for (int q = 0; q < pep.Length; q++)
        {
            result += AminoAcidToCodon(pep.Substring(q, 1));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of input and desired output? Btw. the acronym is LINQ.

Comment: getcodonsforpeptide("MA")   output AGTGAC, AGTGCG  AGTGAT  something like this not sure just by inspecting the two table of codons and amino_acid_per_codon

Comment: So just to ensure I understand what you mean. For each character in the input string there can be multiple matching entries in the AMINOS_PER_CODON table. So for instance, for a given string there could be this many matches for each corresponding character: 1, 2, 3, 2. The resulting *number* of combinations would be 1*2*3*2 = 12. Then, you want each of those combinations, where you want to translate each match from that table into the other table, and get the resulting string, is that it?

Comment: For instance, this pep, "TG" would have 4*4=16 combinations, where two of them would be "ACTGGC" and "GTTGGG" (first and last respectively). Did I get it right?

Comment: Have you considered using a dictionary for amino to codon lookup?

Comment: the peptide MA means MA not AM ie the sequence is important; so for peptide MA you dont have to bother about AM. dictionary wont work because there is no unique key for either codon or amino acid there  are multiple occurences of each in the given tables. I have to tried to create a class to encapsulate  amniacid/codon but it makes the problem even more complex to solve

Comment: See the bottom of my answer for how to declare that dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following two methods:

```
public IEnumerable<string> AminoAcidToCodon(char aminoAcid)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < AMINOS_PER_CODON.Length; k++)
    {
        if (AMINOS_PER_CODON[k] == aminoAcid)
        {
            yield return CODONS[k];
        }
    }
}

public IEnumerable<string> GetCodonsforPeptide(string pep)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pep))
    {
        yield return string.Empty;
        yield break;
    }

    foreach (var codon in AminoAcidToCodon(pep[0]))
        foreach (var codonOfRest in GetCodonsforPeptide(pep.Substring(1)))
            yield return codon + codonOfRest;
}
```

Notes:

- Since each amino acid will have multiple matching codons, your method that returns when it finds the first will only ever match each amino acid once. Instead I created an enumerator method that will `yield return` each matching codon.
- The last method finds all matching codons for the first character of the peptide, and combines each such codon with all the codons made up of the rest of the peptide after the first character.
- I made the `AMINOS_PER_CODON` array use `char` as a type instead. You can easily change the code to use your string array if you want.
- A better approach without two separate arrays would be to create a dictionary mapping each single amino acid character to a list of codon strings.

Example output when passing in `"MA"`:

```
ATGGCT 
ATGGCC 
ATGGCA 
ATGGCG
```

This is because the `M` maps to these:

```
ATG
```

and `A` maps to these:

```
GCT 
GCC 
GCA 
GCG
```

The dictionary I suggest you use would look like this:

```
var codonsByAminoAcid = new Dictionary<char, string[]>
{
    { 'M', new[] { "ATG" } },
    { 'A', new[] { "GCT", "GCC", "GCA", "GCG" } }
};
```

This would replace the `AminoAcidToCodon` method.

You can even build that dictionary from your two arrays:

```
var lookup = 
    CODONS
    .Zip(AMINOS_PER_CODON, (codon, amino) => new { codon, amino })
    .GroupBy(entry => entry.amino)
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key,
        g => g.Select(ge => ge.codon).ToArray());
```

The `GetCodonsforPeptide` method could then look like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetCodonsforPeptide(string pep)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pep))
    {
        yield return string.Empty;
        yield break;
    }

    foreach (var codon in lookup(pep[0]))
        foreach (var codonOfRest in GetCodonsforPeptide(pep.Substring(1)))
            yield return codon + codonOfRest;
}
```

ie. replace the call to that other method by the lookup table.